# Way to view Rails Migration output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration

Is there an easy way to see the actual SQL generated by a rails migration?

I have a situation where a migration to change a column type worked on my local development machine by partially failed on the production server.

My postgreSQL versions are different between local and production (7 on production, 8 on local) so I'm hoping by looking at the SQL generated on the successful migration locally I can work out a SQL statement to run on production to fix things....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some digging and found another way this can be achieved too... (This way only gives you the SQL so it was a bit easier for me to read)

Postgresql will log all the queries executed if you put this line in your config file: (there's an example which has been commented out in the "What to log" section of the config file)

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

Then I rolled back and re-ran my migration locally to find the SQL I was looking for.

This method also gives you the SQL in a format where you can easily paste it into something like PGAdmin's query builder and mess around with it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm surprised there isn't a rails-native way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the log files: log/development.log locally vs log/production.log on your server.

Comment: Thanks Francois! Your suggestion worked fine but I had some trouble as my logfile was HUGE and a bit hard to parse... However, you reminded me of something I'd read a while ago about PostgreSQL's own logfile and I ended up finding a solution that did what I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could set the logger to STDOUT at the top of your migration's `change`, `up`, or `down` methods. Example:

```
class SomMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

    # ...
  end
end
```

Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335695/83743) for adding SQL logging to all rake tasks