# Is it possible to output the SQL change scripts that 'rake db:migrate' produces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to output the SQL change scripts that 'rake db:migrate' produces?

Comment: You should also take a look at this [blog post](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/07/29/how-to-use-rake-tasks-to-generate-migration-sql/)

Comment: `rails console --sandbox` and then run migration from console. The SQL will be printed while it is being executed and everything should rollback when you exit the console

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can create a Rake task in `lib/tasks/`:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Make migration with output'
  task(:migrate_with_sql => :environment) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```

Then call `rake db:migrate_with_sql` to log the migration.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` is the magic, getting a particular migration to run just involves setting the logger prior :)

Comment: This is brilliance

Comment: This is fine but https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335695/972128 feels more elegant.

Answer (score 98):

Building on @qarol but even cooler, add this Rake task to one of your Rake files:

```
task :log => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Then you can call **ANY** Rake task and have the output logged:

```
rake log db:migrate
```

Comment: You can use this:   ActionMailer::Base.logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) to get mailer output as well.

Comment: This worked great and is much more generic.  It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Put this script in a new file called `log_migration.rake` (or whatever) and drop it in the `lib/tasks` directory

Comment: This `ActiveRecord::Base.logger...` statement can also be placed in the default Rakefile to unconditionally output *all* migration statements.

Answer (score 16):

The SQL output is captured in your environment log file e.g. development.log

Comment: There are too many tasks and requests going on that I cannot check it out in development.log

Answer (score 8):

I put together the [capture_migration_sql](https://github.com/bdurand/capture_migration_sql) gem for this purpose. It will dump your migration SQL to files in `db/migration_sql`.

It's overkill if you just need to find a single SQL statement, but is great to have if your production process requires the raw SQL statements. It can also make reviewing complex database changes in code reviews a bit easier since there's no ruby -> SQL mental math required.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more, this gem is super useful and more than answers the question

Comment: Thank you for this super useful gem! Helped me a lot today.

Answer (score 5):

You can run preview SQL in `rails console` like this:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.change_table(:events) do |t|
  t.integer :submission_id, default: 5, null: false
end
#=> ALTER TABLE `events` ADD `submission_id` int DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL
```

So, just prepend your ordinary migration methods with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.` and you are good to go.

There is also `rails console --sandbox` mode which rollbacks changes after you close the console. Though check if it works for your project, somehow for our project with rails 5 + MySQL it doesn't roll back DDL changes.

---

If you have migration files ready, you can also run it directly:

```rb
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").migrate
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").rollback
```