# Validate that the associated model exists when set in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Suppose we have the following `Post` model in Rails:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`user` is not required, but when it is set, we want it to be a valid association (we don't want to have a post that has a `user_id` that isn't in the database). Failing tests:

```
expect(Post.new).to be_valid
expect(Post.new(user_id: 0)).not_to be_valid
expect(Post.new(user: User.create)).to be_valid
```

One solution would be to do:

```
validates_presence_of :user, unless: "user_id.nil?"
```

This will do the required task but isn't really pretty as we don't want to write it for each `belongs_to` we have in our app.

Is there a way to tell rails to check for the existence of the associated model? Isn't that something we want to have by default? (Why would we want an `association_id` that doesn't point to anything?)

Comment: why don't you use foreign keys ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee that an association is valid at the database level, MySQL and PostgreSQL have the ability to enforce the validity of foreign key columns on a table. [Since Rails 4.2](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support), these foreign key constraints can be created as part of a migration.

You could do this in at least two ways in your migration. Either pass the `foreign_key` attribute to [add_reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference):

```
add_reference :posts, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

Or follow `add_reference` with [add_foreign_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key), which also gives you the option of resetting the key when the user is deleted:

```
add_reference :posts, :user, index: true
add_foreign_key :posts, :user, on_delete: :nullify
```

Combine the two approaches by passing a hash to the `foreign_key` attribute of `add_reference` (since Rails 4.2.1):

```
add_reference :posts, :user, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :nullify}
```

If a query breaks the foreign key constraint by updating a `user_id` to point to a non-existent user, the query will fail and raise an exception in Rails.

As you've mentioned, you could also create a validation to check that a `User` exists before creating a `Post`. However, this won't be as strong of a guarantee as a foreign key constraint on the database, since a `User` could be deleted in the time between the validation passing and the `Post` being created.

To help keep references valid at the application level, it would generally be better practice to avoid passing a user id directly to the `Post` constructor. Instead, try to always use a `User` object as input, for example by calling `User.find(:id)`.

Comment: So I have been struggling with this issue for the past 3 days now. I am using Rails 4.2.4 with PostgreSQL, but the constraint is never made, despite adding this restriction: `add_reference :users, :school, index: true, foreign_key: { on_update: :restrict, on_delete: :restrict }`. According to the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) this should work. Do you have any idea what could be wrong? I used `rake db:drop rake db:setup` to no avail. The constraint is simply never made.

Comment: That's odd, does setting the foreign key options separately using `add_foreign_key`  after `add_reference` change anything? Also try outputting the SQL commands that are actually generated by the migration with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100512/is-it-possible-to-output-the-sql-change-scripts-that-rake-dbmigrate-produces/8335695#8335695), to see if `ADD CONSTRAINT` appears at all.

Comment: ADD CONSTRAINT does not appear at all. I checked my rails version in the gemfile and with `rails -v`, which both state `rails 4.2.4`. I tried adding the constraint by using `add_reference` followed by `add_foreign_key`, as well as the `add_reference` way with all the options set. Besides that I also tried setting the relations on the models, using belongs_to and has_many, to no avail. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find the corresponding Rails source code where all the magic happens. I'll probably have to resort to using the Foreigner gem then.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it. The culprit was using `rake db:drop | rake db:setup`. Setup loads a migration from a cached version, which didn't have my edited migration. So I then figured out I actually had to do `rake db:drop | rake db:create | rake db:migrate`. This works because `rake db:create` takes the actual migration files and builds a schema from them. Then, the `rake db:migrate` command executes the migrations properly and sets the constraints. Finally!