# How to check SQL commands executed using rake in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I want to count the votes a user has given to an article and save it somewhere.

I want to check all the SQL `INSERT` or `CREATE` lines executed when we do something like:

```
>$ bundle exec rake db:reset
>$ bundle exec rake db:seed
>$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

Is there a way I can check the SQL commands in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Someone downvoted my question without giving any reason why? :/

Comment: Not clear to me either.

Comment: It's possibly been down voted because the question isn't asked well. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We expect to see evidence of your effort, in this case, what you tried and why it didn't work. You appear to be asking us to write it for you. Also, your question could have been written more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom Rake task and use it whenever you need to log the SQL output:

```
task log: :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Now you can run:

```
bundle exec rake log db:reset
bundle exec rake log db:seed
bundle exec rake log test:prepare
```

See "[Is it possible to output the SQL change scripts that 'rake db:migrate' produces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100512/is-it-possible-to-output-the-sql-change-scripts-that-rake-dbmigrate-produces/8335695#8335695)"

Comment: Could you tell me where I will define a `custom rake task` ?

Comment: `lib/tasks/task_name.rake`