# Heroku release phase fails with no error or logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku

I'm attempting to add Docker onto an old project of mine and host it on Heroku as the dockerized version. I've already got Docker and `docker-compose` up and running locally. Where I am hitting a wall is with pushing this to Heroku.

I moved much of my `docker-compose` commands to a `heroku.yml` file that looks like so:

```yaml
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    RAILS_ENV: production
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - bundle exec rails db:migrate
run:
  web: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

However, whenever I push this to Heroku, I get a successful build, but a failed release:

```bash
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
```

I have also tried having the release command moved to a different file and run like so:

```yaml
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - ./deployment-tasks.sh
```

The `deployment-tasks.sh` file content looked like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

rails db:migrate
```

Heroku release logs always come up empty. I've been at this for a couple of days and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated!

Also, if anyone can tell me how I can quickly iterate and test this without having to re-build my app everytime I push to Heroku, that'd be a huge bonus  - as it stands, I have to wait ~5-10 minutes on each push to see if the changes to the `heroku.yml` works or not

### Other pertinent info:

- Docker base image: `ruby:2.7-alpine3.14`
- Rails version: `6.0.6.1`

#### Edit: `database.yml` configs:

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  # On docker, host must match service name in docker-compose
  host: database

development:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_development
  username: <some_username>
  password: <some_password>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_test
  username: <some_username>
  password: <some_password>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_production
  username: <some_username>
  password: <%= ENV['PORTFOLIO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost
```

Comment: If you want to speed up your feedback cycle, I would create a docker image locally with all the main stuff of your app (all that build stuff that takes up build time), then push that e.g. to github container registry and use it as a base image for your "release phase debugging" Dockerfile.

Comment: You might want to double-check your `config/database.yml` and make sure that you've configured your DB connection for production correctly. Then, for your migration, try this command instead: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. This is what I've been using for my rails projects in Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherTabula - I adjusted the release command to `rake`, but that still fails. I have updated my question with the current `database.yml` configs I'm using. The only thing that's different between this config and the regular, non-dockerized version of my app is the database `host` - I'm not particularly sure what the `host` should be on Heroku, in this case (locally, I have it set to the database service on my `docker-compose` file

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated post, it's pretty clear what's causing the release phase to fail.

The problem here is that you're setting incorrect DB config values:

```yaml
production:
  <<: *default
  database: portfolio_production
  username: <some_username>
  password: <%= ENV['PORTFOLIO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost
```

Once you purchase the **Heroku Postgres** add-on for your app, Heroku will generate a `DATABASE_URL` env var that you can check in your app's **Config Vars**. It should have the following format:

```
postgresql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>
```

You can also find this value in your postgres add-on under the **Resources** tab. Here's an example:

```
postgresql://user1:admin123@localhost:3000/mydb
```

This is what you need to connect to your DB. You can change the configuration of your `database.yml` to use the `url` key instead:

```yaml
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL") %>
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

Or maintain the same settings that you have now. However, make that you set the values through the Config Vars. It is never recommended to manually set the values in your code:

```yaml
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
```

**EDIT**

Another thing that you should check is your Heroku stack. Since you're dockerizing your application, make sure that it is configured with the [container](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) stack. You can set it via the Heroku CLI:

```bash
$ heroku stack:set container
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried using the `DATABASE_URL` in the `database.yml` file and, unfortunately, it still fails - no error messages, no logs :(. Any idea what else may be going on?

Comment: @UmarGhouse At this point, I suggest you install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and investigate at which point did the release phase failed. You can follow this guide [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#checking-release-status-logs).

Comment: Ah, thanks @ChristopherTabula - I already have the heroku CLI and the logs there [weren't too helpful](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QG8Kzuqs20R9XocoicOZZhvq6TgByv1r/view?usp=sharing) - it seems that the release command is not starting at all. Though, still not sure why 

Comment: @UmarGhouse Can you double check your app's heroku [stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#viewing-which-stack-your-app-is-using)? You can verify it through the CLI. I just want to make sure that you're using the `container` stack.

Comment: Yup, it's on the `container` stack - screenshot [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IkEa-SS2VLOSJlvLlxcfPbm_BV70-7G8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @UmarGhouse Other things you can do: 1.) Add [logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100512/is-it-possible-to-output-the-sql-change-scripts-that-rake-dbmigrate-produces) to the rake command to verify that the migration runs correctly 2.) Add logs to your deployment script using `echo` 3.) Verify that your rails app is building correctly by checking the build logs in real-time via the dashboard. If none of these steps are helpful, then you should contact Heroku Support instead. I can't help you anymore than that as I don't have access to your source code & Heroku app.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher Tabula - I added `echo` logs to my deployment script and even those don't fire, so I am guessing that I will need to escalate this to Heroku support.